# I canot use my .d.ts file inside another, problem with module

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I got problem with linking my .d.ts file to another .d.ts file. It returns this error:

> Module '"./consts"' has no exported member 'Devices'. Did you mean
> 'DEVICES'?

I was trying to find out what I'm missing in TS docs, but didn't find my answer. I got same file called consts.ts with exported const DEVICES

My code looks like this:

**consts.d.ts**

```
declare module "@utils/Queries/consts"

export type Devices = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl'

declare const QUERIES: {
  XS: 'xs',
  SM: 'sm',
  MD: 'md',
  LG: 'lg',
  XL: 'xl'
}
```

And now I want to call the devices type inside my index.d.ts and I'm getting the error i wrote above.

**index.d.ts**

```
import { Interpolation } from 'styled-components'

import { Devices } from './consts'

declare module '@utils/Queries/query'

type QueryFunction = (style: Interpolation<any>) => Interpolation<any>

declare const MediaQuery: { [key in Devices]: QueryFunction };
declare const getBreakpointWidth: (name: string) => string;

export { MediaQuery, MediaQuery as default, getBreakpointWidth };
```

And my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "utils/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```